# В зависимости от выбранной радиокнопки делать какое то действие

Tags: php, html, mysql

Имеется форма в ней есть вопрос например любимый цвет:красный,синий,зеленый,белый;

выбор тока одного варианта (radio кнопки) как в файле php сделать так

если выбран красный сделать то то
если синий то другое

как это задаётся какая радиокнопка выбрана?

Comment: if else, switch case

Comment: как ему сказать если выбрана кнопка 1 то делай это(вопрос то как раз и заключается что я не знаю какая конструкция "если выбрана кнопка")

Comment: А точнее для чего вам надо это? Потому что может быть через mysql будет сделать легче

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так, в самом простом случае

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <title>Выбор цвета</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="color" value="red" />Красный<br />
        <input type="radio" name="color" value="green" />Зеленый<br />
        <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" />Синий<br />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>

<?php

if( isset( $_POST['color'] ) )
{
    echo "Цвет: ";
    switch( $_POST['color'] )
    {
        case 'red':
            echo 'Красный';
            break;
        case 'green':
            echo 'Зеленый';
            break;
        case 'blue':
            echo 'Синий';
            break;
    }
}
?>
</body>
```

Comment: что то вывод пустой...посмотрите ещё раз мож ошиблись где то...

Comment: А вы выбрали что-нибудь? Если нет, вывод будет пустой.

Comment: да выбрали

Comment: нужно сохранять файл с кодом с раcширением `.php` и запускать на сервере

Comment: всё так и сделано.

Answer (score 0):

все радиокнопки должны иметь одининаковый атрибут name. 
прим

```
<input type="radio" name="color" value="red">
<input type="radio" name="color" value="blue">
<input type="radio" name="color" value="black">
```

в php проверяешь так:

```
$color = (isset($_REQUEST['color'])) ? $_REQUEST['color'] : false;
```

и действия

```
if(!$color) {
// не выбран цвет.
} else {
echo 'выбран цвет: '.$color;
}
```

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ!!!Буду пробывать)))))))

Comment: ну и в догонку с усложнением очень интересно:
пример форма про машины(марка,цвет,год выпуска,пробег) пользователь выбирает радиокнопкой цвет на форме...а из базы данных выбираются все машины этого цвета.

Comment: @dracon57, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

По поводу дополнения: попробуйте сначала что-то сделать сами. Если не получится, покажите код. Пока это больше похоже на работу за автора.